# WordPress page.php not show posts

Tags: wordpress

If I add to sidebar this code I can't display anything in page.php I try reset query but no result.

```
<?php
    $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'kalba' => 'lt',
            'posts_per_page' => 7
                 );

$new_query = new WP_Query();
$new_query->query($args);
?>

<?php if ($new_query->have_posts()) : ?> 
<?php while ($new_query->have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php $new_query->the_post();?>     

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<div class="sidebar-line"></div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

got confuse y you are using

```
'kalba' => 'lt',
```

in your argument. wp_query have no any such argument 'kalba'

may be you can try and change your argument  lik

```
$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => 7
                 );
```

like this 
.. hope it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Before loop I add `<?php rewind_posts(); ?>` and when it work.